# (Rails) Does scoping apply when calling model.association.find?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For example, I have:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end

one_school = School.first
```

Is there a speed difference between using:

```
Student.find :all, :conditions => { :first_name => "John", :school_id => one_school.id }
```

and

```
one_school.students.find :all, :conditions => { :first_name => "John" }
```

I was wondering if calling "one_school.students.find" will iterate through ALL the student records, or will they iterate through the student records belonging to one_school only?

This is more of a question on performance. I need to know if the latter query really is faster in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically the same (Rails will use a `join` in both cases), you can see the query and it's performance in your server console and compare. To enhance performance make sure you index `school_id` on your students table.

Comment: Ah, alright, was hoping that wasn't the case. I guess I'll have to find other ways to optimize this. :D The needed attributes have already been indexed. Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: consider using a documents-based database which can reduce joins and provide better performance in certain scenarios, take a look at mongodb for example (which also hooks very well in Rails).